# apt-get is not using configured proxy automatically

Tags: apt, proxy

I defined `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` both in ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile, but by running `apt-get` commands these variables are not considered and I have to specify it manually (`sudo http_proxy=*** apt-***`).
This is really annoying! How can I fix this? (I've already restarted the OS)

Comment: If you can't add proxy settings in `/etc/apt`, use `sudo -E apt-...`.